# gtkmm include not working windows 7

Tags: netbeans, windows-7, include, mingw, gtkmm

i installed the gtkmm gui libraries(for c++), but i can't get it to work. c:\gtkmm64\bin is on Path, but my ide says only the include files under c:\mingw\include\something are there. i use netbeans as my ide, i run windows 7, my compiler is mingw.

Comment: I think you'd get a more effective answer on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring Gtkmm to work can somewhat be a nightmare.

You need to do the following on project properties:

- On "C++ compiler" section, you'll have to put all includes in the "Include Directories" section. Be aware that there are a lot of .h files sown there, not only gtkmm/include is needed. For example, glib/include will also be needed, etc.
- On the "Linker" section, click in Libraries. You have to put there all libraries in the gtkmm package. As in the previous seciton, not only gtkmm/lib is needed: glib/lib, pango/lib, etc. will also be needed.

You're done when the compiler stops complaining.